# Swift iOS 9+ before app closes/before app opens

Tags: ios, swift

I want, using Swift in iOS, to capture a variable before the app closes from a subview and place it in storage, and prior to the app gets too far along on re-open restore this variable.

I know how to get and set, I just am hoping to stumble across the events that trigger before the app closes and shortly after it launchers.

Comment: AppDelegate. There's comments next to each delegate method when you first create a project that tell you what each of them do.

Comment: perfect! thanks! I wonder since this is so simple, and a blunder of an over site, should I delete this question?

Comment: I don't develop iOS, so can't myself say whether the question should be kept. If you think someone might have the same question, and you cannot find a duplicate now that you know the answer, then there may be value in keeping it.

Answer (score 0):

You should do this in the `AppDelegate.swift` file.